# Block process outgoing requests

Tags: internet, process, port

I have a program on my computer that repeatedly tries to access a webaddress that no longer exists or something, causing it to hang for minutes on end while, I guess, it waits or cycles attempts to receive an answer.

Is there a way to block outgoing requests to a certain address but not ALL from a process?

I tried the hosts file but the program still hangs, I guess, waiting for it to timeout or something.

Comment: Windows pC? If so use this software, after install go into Main Panel and turn notifications ON, then you will a notification when it tries to go out, then you can choose to block it.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>https://binisoft.org/wfc

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: @Ecstasy, Windows 7 and 10